# How to trace WCF serialization issues / exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-faults, wcf-serialization

I occasionally run into the problem that an application exception is thrown during the WCF-serialization (after returning a DataContract from my OperationContract). The only (and less meaningfull) message I get is

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
>   : The underlying connection was
>   closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.

without any insight to the inner exception, which makes it really hard to find out what caused the error during serialization.

Does someone know a good way how you can trace, log and debug these exceptions? Or even better can I catch the exception, handle them and send a defined FaulMessage to the client?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get the inner exception if you configure your service behavior like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
               <behavior name="YourServiceBehaviour">
                   ...
                   <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                   ...
               </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Additionally you can enable tracing. Did not find a good article now, but maybe this gets you started:

http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/03/24/using-of-wcf-trace.aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply. The  includeExceptionDetailInFaults  attribute only applies for exceptions that occur inside your OperationContract boundaries. issues during serialization occur outside these boundaries. Your second proposal might be a solution to log (but not handle) these issues. I will take a deeper look it.

Comment: Many thanks for the link. Logging helped me to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, and it was a serialization issue... sometimes I was sending a DataTable without any column, in that case the channel just closed without any error or trace.